# How to let auto-complete use java mode in Jdee mode?

Tags: java, emacs, autocomplete, jdee

guys

I installed jdee in my emacs and it works well, but I fins that it cannot active auto-complete.

Example: When I open a new .java file in emacs, and I input "imp", auto-complete cannot active.

The problem is .java file open in emacs in "jdee-mode" because jdee. But the auto-complete only work on "java-mode", the evidence is AC works well when I change the jave-mode filename, which in AC/dict, to jdee-mode.

So I thought two solutions about this:

1. make AC use java-mode even in jdee-mode
2. make emacs change the filename of java-mode to jdee-mode after every update jdee.

Dose anyone know how to make them? Or has better solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this existing stackoverflow question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715296/emacs-auto-complete-dont-work-with-jde

Comment: I had read that question, and that is why I know change filename will work (the solution in commit, answer can't work for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `jde-mode` to `ac-modes` to make AC works with `jde-mode` too.

```
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'jde-mode)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I use jdee-mode and jde-mode, but both of them didn't work

Answer (score 2):

JDEE doesn't support autocomplete nor company-mode, yet. But it does have its own completion mechanism. To use it create JDEE project file (prj.el) in your project directory, with the following content:

```
(jdee-project-file-version "1.0")
(jdee-set-variables
 '(jdee-compile-option-classpath (quote ("./out")))
 '(jdee-compile-option-directory "./out")
 '(jdee-built-class-path (quote ("./out")))
 '(jdee-db-option-classpath (quote ("./out")))
 '(jdee-run-option-classpath (quote ("./out")))
 '(jdee-run-working-directory ".")
 '(jdee-sourcepath (quote ("./src"))))
```

"./out" is the path to compiled classes. "./src" is the path to your sources. JDEE requires JDEE-Server that is at GH (http://github.com/jdee-emacs/jdee-server). Then you can go to a Java file in your project and do "jdee-complete-menu". **This is for JDEE from MELPA**.

Comment: That looks like a good idea, and I submit this problem to AC-project on github. He give me other [solution](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/issues/429).